# emacs fails to clear image cache

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs24

So firs of all

```
ELISP> (version)
"Aquamacs 3.2 GNU Emacs 24.4.51.2\n(x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0, NS apple-appkit-1343.14)\n of 2014-11-07 (Aquamacs-3.2) on watson.local"
```

Then I create a solid green image

```
$ convert -size 100x100 "xc:#009900" /tmp/whatever.png
```

Then I open it in emacs (aquamacs) `C-x C-f /tmp/whatever.png` and it is indeed green.

Then `M-: (clear-image-cache)`.

Then run on a shell.

```
$ convert -size 100x100 "xc:#990000" /tmp/whatever.png
```

Check that the image with an external program and it is indeed red now.

I `M-x revert-buffer` on the emacs buffer but the image is still green...

I tried closing the buffer and `find-file` again and still green.

Restart Aquamacs and the image is now red as it should. Am I missing something?

Comment: Dunno whether this helps at all, but you might try (1) passing `t` to `clear-image-cache` or (2) using function `remove-images` in the buffer where the image was displayed. And then redisplay whichever images you want there.

Comment: neither of those worked but thank you

Comment: Perhaps an Aquamacs bug, since with GNU Emacs 24.5.50.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0, NS apple-appkit-1347.57), just reverting the buffer is enough to change the color correctly, no image cache manipulation needed.

Answer (score 0):

i ran into the same issue (in babel) and solved it by clearing the image cache and toggling display:

```
(defun redisplay-images ()
  (clear-image-cache)
  (org-redisplay-inline-images))

(add-hook 'org-babel-after-execute-hook 'redisplay-images)
```

hope it works for you